# In apache, how to map site.example.com to example.com/site

Tags: apache, subdomain

I'm sure there is documentation for how to do this, but I don't know what it's called so I don't even know how to start searching.

On my webserver, `example.com`, i have a site called `site`. It's accessed by going to `example.com/site`.

I want it instead to be `site.example.com`.

Can someone point me to apache documentation to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use **virtual host**. Edit the file called `.../apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and add this line:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "[PATH-TO-APACHE]/Apache2.2/htdocs/tema"
    ServerName site.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course you need also to enable virtual hosts on apache editing the `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Thanks, do I only need to enable virtual hosts by creating `virtual.conf` with the content `NameVirtualHost *` under `apache2/conf.d`?

Comment: @B.VB. You can enable it removing the '#' before this line Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf in the httpd.conf . Anyway you can find a lot of stuff searching for "Enable virtual hosts on [YOUR-OPERATING-SYSTEM]"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to rewrite or redirect people from the subfolder to a subdomain? Why not create a virtual host / subdomain then do 301 from the old subfolder to the subdomain?

This is a good tutorial on creating subdomains

http://thinkingnectar.com/2008/getting-ubuntu-to-work-creating-subdomain-in-localhost/

Comment: No i don't want to redirect from a subfolder to a subdomain.. In fact I dont want a subdomain at all. I want site.example.com to reference example.com/site (as I plan to have other sites on this host, and don't want to have them all be example.com/site{a, b, c}

Comment: What do you mean by site.example.com reference example.com/site? Do you mean have them both display the same content?